# Querying DynamoDB with node.js between values

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Querying dynamoDB table with node.js. The DynamoDB table has key of Timestamp, represented by an integer. In this case, I left :timestampStart as 1 and timestampEnd as 10 as an example.

```
    var params = {
        TableName: "Table2",
        KeyConditionExpression:"Timestamp = :ts BETWEEN :timestampStart AND :timestampEnd",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":ts":"Timestamp",
            ":timestampStart": 1,
            ":timestampEnd": 10
        }
    };
```

The :ts is not correct, I can see this. I want to return any rows found with a Timestamp value between timestampStart and timestampEnd.

Error message:

> "errorMessage": "Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error;
>   token: \"BETWEEN\", near: \":ts BETWEEN :timestampStart\"",

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `Timestamp` is the partition key and not the sort key. Then, you have two problems:

1. In a [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operation, you cannot perform a comparison test (<, >, BETWEEN, ...) on the partition key. The condition must perform an equality test (=) on a single partition key value and, *optionally*, one of several comparison tests on a single sort key value. For example:

   `KeyConditionExpression: 'HashKey = :hkey and RangeKey > :rkey'`
2. You have a syntax error in your `KeyConditionExpression`, *obviously*. Keep in mind that `Timestamp` is a [reserved word](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) in DynamoDB. So, you'll have to use `ExpressionAttributeNames` for that:

(Assuming you have an `Id` partition key and `Timestamp` sort key)

```
var params = {
   TableName: "Table2",
   KeyConditionExpression: "Id = :id AND #DocTimestamp BETWEEN :start AND :end",
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
     '#DocTimestamp': 'Timestamp'
   },
   ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":id": "SOME VALUE",
     ":start": 1,
     ":end": 10
   }
 };
```

Comment: If I have Timestamp as the partition key, would creating a secondary global index with the Timestamp as the sort key overcome the problems here? I could then create an equality statement

Comment: Solved with the addition of a secondary index